# Can I use Unity's default Analytics?

Tags: airconsole

Can I implement Unity's default Analytics into AirConsole game?
Are there any restrictions or limitations that i should have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Unity Analytics just like in any other project.